# Obtener los resultados de varios Spinners creados dinámicamente

Tags: android, android-studio, spinner

Mi problema es el siguiente:

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación de encuestas, compuesta principalmente por spinners y radiobuttons. Estos spinners se crean dinámicamente (programáticamente), y una encuesta pueden aparecer 2, 3, 40... o ningún spinner.

Formar la estructura de la encuesta es sencillo. Ahora bien, no sé cómo extraer los datos de cada spinner si hay más de uno. Siempre me retorna el valor del último de ellos.

Así lo tengo programado (resumido):

```
 public void construyeEncuesta(){
        //cuestionesCC es un ArrayList con el número de Spinners(1) y de RadioButtons(2)
        for (int i=0; i<cuestionesCC.size();i++) {

            switch (codTipoRespuestasCC.get(i)){

                // Pregunta de tipo 1 a 10
                case "1":

                    createSpinner();
                    break;

                // Pregunta de tipo SI / NO
                case "2":

                    createRadioGroup();
                    break;  
            }
        }
    }


  //Aquí se crea dinámicamente el Spinner    
  public void createSpinner(){

        String[] numbers = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.numbers1to10);
        spinner = new Spinner(this);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, numbers);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        linearEncuesta.addView(spinner); }
```

Esto me crea una serie de Spinners. Mi problema (más bien mi novatez) es que quiero saber qué resultado me arroja cada uno de los spinners. Yo lo hago así, pero seguro que está mal.

```
public void obtieneRespuestas(){

        for (int i=0; i<codTipoRespuestasCC.size();i++){

            switch (codTipoRespuestasCC.get(i)){

                case "1":                    
                   String valorSpinner = String.valueOf(spinner.getSelectedItem());
                   Log.e("Valor Spinner: ", valorSpinner);


                    Log.e("1: ", "tipo 1 a 10");
                    break;

                case "2":

                    Log.e("2: ", "tipo si/no");
                    break;

            }
        }

    }
```

Pero claro, si hay más de un spinner, en todos los casos me devuelve siempre el valor del último de ellos.

¿Qué me falta?... (además de echarle muchas más horas a esto de la programación)

Gracias y un saludo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo estas realizando casí correctamente, solo que el valor del `Spinner` se obtiene mediante:

```
getSelectedItem().toString()
```

Ejemplo:

```
 //String valorSpinner = String.valueOf(spinner.getSelectedItem());
   String valorSpinner = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
   Log.e("Valor Spinner: ", valorSpinner);
```

---

> no sé cómo extraer los datos de cada `spinner` si hay más de uno

Si estas creando los `Spinner` programáticamente puedes definir un "tag" a tus "Spinner" para poder identificarlos, para esto puedes enviar el valor del tag a tu método, y asignarlo a el Spinner que es creado programaticamente.

```
public void createSpinner(String tag){

    String[] numbers = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.numbers1to10);
    spinner = new Spinner(this);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, numbers);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    //Define tag.
    spinner.setTag(tag);

    linearEncuesta.addView(spinner);
}
```

Suponiendo que definiste un tag llamado "spinner1", de esta forma podrías obtener las propiedades del `Spinner` creado con ese tag:

```
 spinner = linearEncuesta.findViewWithTag("spinner1");
```

Comment: Gracias por el comentario! Efectivamente, ahí tenía el primero de los fallos. Aún me queda por resolver cómo distinguir cuando tengo, por ejemplo, 2 spinners. Cómo yo lo tengo, ambos spinners me devuelven siempre el valor del segundo.

Comment: Obtienes cada referencia de los Spinner dentro de variables mediante findViewById() es así? @Mimmetico

Comment: Por ahí sospecho que viene el problema. Al crear los Spinners programáticamente, no tengo muy claro cómo hacerles referencias. Por ejemplo, si la aplicación me genera 3 spinners, ¿cómo puedo ponerles 3 identificadores y luego meterlas en variables? y, después, hacer referencia a sus respectivos valores... estoy liado con todo ese embrollo

Comment: No importa si creaste programáticamente los Spinner, podrías definir un Tag para identificarlos, revisa la edición a mi respuesta, @Mimmetico

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. Al final el tema de los Tag fue la pista definitiva para resolver mi duda. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Si mal no entiendo te recomendaría usar un Listener, y dentro guardar la info que devuelve.

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
    // Aca guardate los datos. 
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
    // your code here
}
```

});